# Broken drag-n-drop file/folder escaping to Terminal in OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-elcapitan

`Terminal` on OS X recently began pasting folders and files in with drag and drop that are not being escaped properly.  Traditionally when you drag a file into Terminal, you'll get a result that has, for example, spaces escaped with a `\`, etc.  This no longer functions as such.

Incidentally `iTerm` does still work, so this is an issue that appears to be limited to `Terminal` only on OS X (specifically 10.11.2 for me).

I assume that this is some kind of a preference setting that has been modified unexpectedly.  Any idea as to what may be the resolution?

Comment: I asked [a similar question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/223948/11572) over at Ask Different, which may be a better venue than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Glad you found the solution!  Thanks @bdesham